# How do I search through terms within a list in prolog?

Tags: list, search, prolog

I have a list that looks like this [(Tony, 1234), (Bob, 2345), (Alan, 3456)].

I need to create a function that will search through the list by the name and then show the number. So something like: 
    find_user_id(Tony, [(Tony, 1234), (Bob, 2345), (Alan, 3456)], I). 
I being the value of the ID of the user found.

Comment: Just to clarify terminology, that's not a list within a list in the Prolog sense. Those are terms or structures within a list, where the terms are of the form `(X, Y)`.

Comment: I was unsure of the wording, but how I wrote it out is how it needs to be done. So searching with terms.

Comment: I think @CapelliC has you covered on the how-to

Answer (score 1):

use [memberchk](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=memberchk/2)/2:

```
?- memberchk((tony,Val), [(tony, 1234), (bob, 2345), (blan, 3456)]).
```